# What does the compiler do to a function which contains only one function call

Tags: c

As the title suggests, what happens if I have:

```
void a(uint8_t i) {
  b(i, 0);
}
```

Will a compiler be able to replace a call to a(i) with b(i, 0)?

Also, in either case, would the following be considered good practice to replace the above:

```
#define a(i) b(i, 0)
```

Comment: The former is "tail call elimination", which is a known optimization strategy; the latter is just no no no.

Comment: It will do that (and much more) if the definition of `a()` is visible at the point of use, or if the build system is instructed to perform link time or whole program optimization. (Which implies that with a standard build system `a()` cannot be inlined if it resides in a different translation unit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty easy to test. If the call to `a` is in the same compilation unit most compilers will optimize it. Let's see what happens:

```
$ cat > foo.c
void b(int, int);

void
a(int a)
{
        b(a, 0);
}

void
foo(void)
{
        a(17);
}
```

Then compile it to just assembler with some basic optimizations (I added omit-frame-pointer to create cleaner output, you can verify that exactly the same thing will happen without that flag):

```
$ cc -fomit-frame-pointer -S -O2 foo.c
```

And then look at the output (I cleaned it up and just kept the code, there's lot of annotations in generated assembler that aren't relevant here):

```
$ cat foo.s
a:
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    jmp b
foo:
    xorl    %esi, %esi
    movl    $17, %edi
    jmp b
```

So we can see here that the compiler first generated a normal function `a` that calls `b` (except it's tail call optimized, so it's jmp instead of a call). Then when compiling `foo` instead of calling `a` it just inlined it.

The compiler I used in this case was a relatively old version of gcc, I also checked that clang does the exact same thing. This is pretty standard optimization and as long as the compiler does any inlining, a simple function like this will always be inlined.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on a few things, not least of which is your choice of toolchain (compiler, linker, etc) and optimisation settings.

If the compiler has visibility of the definition of `a()` - not just a declaration - it might elect to inline `a()`.    A compiler is not required to do that but, depending on optimisation settings and quality of implementation of the compiler itself, it might.   Your case is, however, a fairly common and straight-forward optimisation for modern compilers.

If the function is not declared `static` (which very over-simplistically makes it local to a particular compilation unit) then most compilers will still keep a definition of the function `a()` in the object file, so it can be linked in with other object files (for other compilation units).   Even if it choose to inline calls of the function within the compilation unit that defines it.

If the function is declared `inline` (and the compiler has visibility of the definition) the same actually applies.   `inline` is a hint which the standard permits a compiler to ignore, no matter how adamant the programmer is.   In practice, modern compilers can often do a better job of deciding which functions to inline than a programmer can.

If you have code that stores the address of `a()` (e.g. in a pointer to function) the compiler might elect to not inline it.

Even if the compiler does not inline the function, a smart linker might choose to (in effect) inline it.   Most C implementations, however, use a traditional dumb linker as part of the toolchain - so this type of link-time optimisation is unlikely in practice.

Even if the linker doesn't, some virtual machine host environments might elect to inline at run time.     This would be highly unusual for a C program  but not beyond realms of possibility.

Personally, I wouldn't worry about it.   There will be few observable differences (e.g. in program performance, size, etc) whether the compiler does this style of optimisation or not, unless you have a truly large number of such functions.

I would not use a macro.   If you really don't want to type `, 0` whenever you use `b()`, then simply write your function `a()`, and let the compiler worry about it.    Only try to optimise further by hand if performance measures and profiling show your function `a()` is a performance hotspot.   Which it probably won't be.

Or, use C++, and declare the function `b()` with a default value of `0` for the second argument.  ;)

Comment: It's not that unusual any longer. gcc has -flto (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and optimizes across translation units if they are provided to a single gcc call.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will most likely optimize this code, and make it an [inline function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function):

```
inline void a(uint8_t i) {
  b(i, 0);
}
```

So calls like `a(i)` will indeed be replaced with `b(i, 0)`

Comment: It will not, because "a" has to be exported in the global symbol table, it might be referenced from "outside"

Comment: @M.M theoretically, maybe (haven't thought that through). Do you know a compiler, which would really do that?

Comment: @Ctx gcc does this. So does clang. Pretty trivial to test.

Comment: @Ctx AFAIK inlineing and external linkage are not mutually exclusive. Compilers can heuristically inline any function that seems fitting. Gcc does that with O2 optimization level.

Comment: Thanks, I indeed haven't thought of that possibility.